# How to move index 0 (zero) to end of array using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I would like to **move** the index 0 to **end of array using NSPredicate**.

I am using Core Data and I having an entity called **Link** that is have an attribute called **orderingLink** which is **Integer 64** type.

I've tried to use this follow code and i've expected to move the index 0 to end of array.

```
open func fetchLinkRequest(_ links: [Links]? = nil) -> NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: T.entityName)

    let sort1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "orderingLink", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort1]

    var predicates = [NSPredicate]()
    predicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "orderingLink != 0 ", argumentArray: [links]))
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicate.LogicalType.and, subpredicates: predicates)

   return fetchRequest
```

Although, this code don't show the index 0 in array, and this was my latest progress in order to move the index 0 to end of array.
Please, help me how to solve this problem.
Thank You.

Comment: Your question is not clear, what does it mean to move an index? Do you want to modify an attribute or do you simply want to reverse the sort order?

Comment: You cannot do this with a predicate. Just fetch the stuff then `remove` the item `at` index 0 and `append` it.

Comment: Predicate doesn't sort, it filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is "You can't." Predicates let you sort or filter arrays or databases, but not modify them.